Overfull \hbox in bibliography URL despite hfuzz
Despite using hfuzz=… to hide warnings for (sufficiently small) overfull boxes, an overfull box happening in an URL in my bibliography still displays a warning. Why? How can I get rid of the warning?
To illustrate, in the following example, the overfull line in the main text generates no warning (which shows that hfuzz is in effect), but the (less) overfull line in the bibliography does.
\begin{filecontents}{example.bib}
  @techreport{report,
    author = {Unknown, U. and Unknown, U.},
    institution = {Institution},
    title = {Some title},
    url = {https://www.example.com/some-very-long-url-with-much-text/and-a-second-part-that-is-overly-long-as-well-and-fills-the-line/},
    year = {2015}
  }
\end{filecontents}
 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}

\hfuzz=4cm

\begin{document}
This url \url{http://www.example.com/is-overly-long-but-raises-no-warnings/is-overly-long-but-raises-no-warnings/is-overly-long-but-raises-no-warnings} 
\citep{report}.

\bibliography{example}

\end{document}


If you add
\show\thebibliography


You will see
> \thebibliography=\long macro:
#1->\bibsection \parindent \z@ \bibpreamble \bibfont \list {\@biblabel {\the \c
@NAT@ctr }}{\@bibsetup {#1}\global \c@NAT@ctr \z@ }\ifNAT@openbib \renewcommand
 \newblock {\par }\else \renewcommand \newblock {\hskip .11em \@plus .33em \@mi
nus .07em}\fi \sloppy \clubpenalty 4000\widowpenalty 4000 \sfcode `\.\@m \let \
NAT@bibitem@first@sw \@firstoftwo \let \citeN \cite \let \shortcite \cite \let 
\citeasnoun \cite .
l.18 \show\thebibliography

so it does \sloppy which is
\DeclareRobustCommand\sloppy{%
  \tolerance 9999%
  \emergencystretch 3em%
  \hfuzz .5\p@
  \vfuzz\hfuzz}

So \hfuzz is reset to .5pt within the bibliography. You could redefine \sloppy to have a bigger hfuzz or add
\usepackage{xurl}

so the line is not overfull

